# React components have css files which i did not imported

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, compass-sass

i just imported one scss file in my component landing page

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import FeaturedRestaurant from '../restaurant/RestaurantFeatured';
import './css/landing_style.scss';
```

but when i see to console it has six css files which i imported in other components, I have doubt like webpack make available scss file to all other components

screen shot is below
[image]

this is my webpack config

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
require('babel-core/register');
require('babel-polyfill');

module.exports = {
  entry: ['babel-polyfill', './src/index.js'],
  output: {
    path: '__dirname',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel',
        exclude: /node_modules/,

        query: {
          cacheDirectory: true,
          presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-1']
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.sass$/,
        loaders: ['style', 'css', 'sass']
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loaders: ['style', 'css', 'sass']
      },
      {
        test: /\.sass$/,
        loaders: ['style', 'css', 'sass']
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loaders: ['style', 'css', 'sass']
      }
    ]
  },
  devServer: {
    port: 3000,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    contentBase: './',
    proxy: {
      '/auth/google': {
        target: 'http://localhost:5000'
      },
      '/api/*': {
        target: 'http://localhost:5000'
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: can you post your `webpack.config.js ` file in order to have better understanding

Comment: webpack config has been added in question

Answer (score 0):

A lot of times sass files can import other assets or style sheets.

```
// base.scss

@import 'main.scss';

body {
  font: 100% Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: #efefef;
}
```

Once the page is transpiled it will look like you added multiple style sheets if that is the case.

Comment: no this is  not a the case there are all style sheets are present even i didnot import them